# Can you backup with Duplicity (or similar) with Amazon Cloud Drive?

Tags: backup, cloud, duplicity

There are a number of excellent tutorials on using duplicity (and sometimes duply to simplify) to backup to Amazon S3:

http://old.blog.phusion.nl/2013/11/11/duplicity-s3-easy-cheap-encrypted-automated-full-disk-backups-for-your-servers/

I have used a few of these with great success, but I was wondering if it would be possible to modify them somehow to use the new [Amazon Cloud Drive](https://www.amazon.co.uk/clouddrive/home) as this now offers "unlimited" space for only $60 per year. (sorry if that sounds like an advert!)

It seems like the protocols are very similar, I just would have no idea where to start with authentication and options!

Answer (score 1):

Authentication is done via "Login with Amazon" which is based on OAuth2. There is a getting started guide [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/getting-started).  They offer an HTTP [API](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/nodes) for accessing the data. I never looked at the duplicity connectors, but there might be some that utilize HTTP already.

Answer (score 0):

[This GitHub repo](https://github.com/breunigs/duplicity-amazondrive) seems to provide the required backend for duplicity to work with Amazon Cloud Drive.

Instructions:

Get the latest version from Launchpad (go [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eduplicity-team/duplicity/0.8-series/view/head:/duplicity/backends/adbackend.py) and click **download file** to get the raw version)

`cd` to wherever the file was saved and do

```
cp adbackend.py /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/
```

to use, run

```
duplicity source_path ad:///backup/my_new_backup
```